# Box Net: How to search files with matching file name only using /search

Tags: box-api

I am using following query to search which searches file title, description and body content.

boxSearch = boxNetContext.getBoxClient().getSearchManager().search(searchFileName, boxDefaultRequestObject);
folderItems = boxSearch.getEntries();

I want to limit search to file title alone.

How to query to search only file titles?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to [Search](http://developers.box.com/docs/#search) by title alone. You must post-process the items returned by Box to find those with matching titles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion from my experience on Android platform.

find the file of com.box.boxjavalibv2.requests.SearchRequest.java, change the code as below

```
public SearchRequest(final IBoxConfig config, final IBoxJSONParser parser, final String searchQuery, BoxDefaultRequestObject requestObject)
        throws BoxRestException {
        super(config, parser, URI, RestMethod.GET, requestObject);
        addQueryParam("query", searchQuery);
}
```

To

```
public SearchRequest(final IBoxConfig config, final IBoxJSONParser parser, final String searchQuery, BoxDefaultRequestObject requestObject)
    throws BoxRestException {
    super(config, parser, URI, RestMethod.GET, requestObject);
    addQueryParam("query", searchQuery);
    addQueryParam("type", "file");
}
```

Then the result are pure files without folder.

Good Luck.